Reverse file versions in S3 bucket
I have a file in S3 which will have several versions. I was able to list all versions of the file using boto3 library and display it but I want to reverse the oldest version first so that I can pick oldest version first for processing. Can anyone please guide how can I achieve this ? Tried several options but nothing seems working as expected.
Many thanks in advance.
Existing code:
import json
import boto3
import re
import sys

s3_r = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'dummy-data-bucket'
file_key = 'employee_details/emp.csv'

def s3versions(bucket, prefix):
    '''List all versions of files in s3.'''
    bucket = s3_r.Bucket(bucket)
    versions = bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix = prefix)
    for version in versions:
        object = version.get()
        version_id = object.get('VersionId')
        if version_id != 'null':      
            path = version.object_key
            last_modified = object.get('LastModified')
            print(path, version_id, last_modified,  sep = '\t')
                
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3versions(bucket_name,file_key)

Output received:
employee_details/emp.csv    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZ.V0AYWKkz7hOyN    2024-10-25 14:40:56+00:00
employee_details/emp.csv    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhdrHh8Yi_2XZ6W9    2024-10-25 14:38:54+00:00
employee_details/emp.csv    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXgg1FxEgb.TDnxnR    2024-10-25 14:37:17+00:00

Expected output:
employee_details/emp.csv    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXgg1FxEgb.TDnxnR    2024-10-25 14:37:17+00:00
employee_details/emp.csv    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXhdrHh8Yi_2XZ6W9    2024-10-25 14:38:54+00:00
employee_details/emp.csv    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZ.V0AYWKkz7hOyN    2024-10-25 14:40:56+00:00


You can simply use reversed() to traverse the iterator in the other direction. for version in reversed(versions):

You could simply add the key/timestamp tuple to a list then finally iterate over the list in reverse.

@Ben for version in reversed(versions): does not work. Gives error: "errorMessage": "'s3.Bucket.object_versionsCollection' object is not reversible",   "errorType": "TypeError"

reversed(list(versions)) should work

Thanks @AnonCoward for version in reversed(list(versions)): worked. Thanks for the help.

Here is the updated code, which provides the expected results.
Thanks @AnonCoward for the suggestion.
import boto3
import sys

s3_r = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'dummy-data-bucket'
file_key = 'employee_details/emp.csv'

def s3versions(bucket, prefix):
    '''List all versions of files in s3.'''
    bucket = s3_r.Bucket(bucket)
    versions = bucket.object_versions.filter(Prefix = prefix)
    for version in reversed(list(versions)):
        object = version.get()
        version_id = object.get('VersionId')
        if version_id != 'null':      
            path = version.object_key
            last_modified = object.get('LastModified')
            print(path, version_id, last_modified,  sep = '\t')
                
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3versions(bucket_name,file_key)

